# Prevent direct selection from NL training

Tags: bixby

I matched the concept in selection-of in NL training so that it could now accept the input and display result when i voice-input the option. But the downside of this is it will directly show the result even though i am not in the selection page. Is there any way to prevent this? My approach is match goal of NL with the concept of selection option, with **at prompt for** the concept

[Update] Would like to show the menu to the user first before they make their selection. The menu can be shown when I running an action

[image][image]

Where playNews> getNews> getMenu (a selection-of input view)

```
action (getNews) {
    type (Constructor)
    description (__DESCRIPTION__)
    collect {
        input (whatuserwant){
            type (userWantToHear)
            min (Required) max (One)
            default-init{
                intent{
                    goal: getMenu
                }
            }
            default-select{
                with-rule{
                    select-first
                }
            }

        }
    }
    output (newsAudio)
}
```

To allow voice-input selection, i add training for the concept[image]

So it is able to select selection from the menu, **but** it also will accept the selection and run even though i am not in the menu yet. **Is it possible to get rid of this?** Or is this the behaviour of Bixby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I would remove `default-select` and add `prompt-behavior (AlwaysElicitation)` to the input. [Read more in our DOC.](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.input.prompt-behavior)

You may also want to check [this example in GitHub](https://github.com/MinChengVivLabs/example.voiceInput) to see how to construct an input view selection from other input of the action. This example is a simplified version of how QuizIt handles the selection part. You may also want to check the training to see how Bixby would take different action with/without the top-level "A" training example.

The input prompt should be easy and simple as you expect: present a list with a message, then user can either tap, or voice select, and able to continue the action.

Here are some additional info you might find useful:

1. Bixby platform would try to match every property of a struct when an input is missing, so mark the property as `visibility (Private)` to prevent that. You can also use `prompt-behavior (AlwaysSelection)` to force a selection of an input.
2. In case of prompt/continuation training, Bixby would treat it as top-level training is no other training could fit. For example a simple quiz capsule that would construct a default quiz, top level utterance "A" would be treated as if answering the first question as A. To prevent this, just add a training example of "A" and match it to the action you want. Bixby would know to use this top-level training instead of the prompt training.

Comment: I had update the question with more information, thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Updated, and I think you should be able to solve the issue with some help from the sample capsule I made.

Comment: Yes! thank you for your help,`prompt-behaviour(AlwaysElicitation)` didn't helped as it will force me to select another time in a new view after i select from the menu. While your code's training file really helped me a lot in understanding the concept.